# Only the last Android app is installed

Tags: java, android

I have 2 android applications in eclipse, I create the apk and then I copy them to the device and install them. The problem is that only the last one is installed.

I install app A. OK

I install app B. B is ok but A is gone.

What am I doing wrong?
What should I change in the Manifest xml?

Thanks

Comment: Do both your applications **A** and **B** have the same `Package Names`?

Comment: I guess both app have same `package name`?

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem,@Siddharth Lele:  Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Identifies its application from the

```
 package="your.package.name"
```

If you want **A** and **B** to be two separate apps then you need to give different package names to both applications.

TIP: when you change the package name do not forget to update all references.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have different `Package Names` for both applications in their respective `Manifest.XML` files.

For example:

**Application A:**

Change the Package Name: `package="com.something.A"`

**Application B:**

Change the Package Name: `package="com.something.B"`

These are just illustrations. Do choose your own naming convention though.

You will also have to make changes to the `packages` under the **src** folder in both your applications. You will not be able to publish applications to Google Play if they have the same `Package Names`

Comment: Thanks that was the problem (+1)